AJAX function is not getting called properly
so i was trying to fix my ajax function that does not work properly like before. I want to use my select option value to only show the selected value's ajax result. The current one is not working (selected option can be selected but the ajax is not changing by the selected value, just the first one on the selected option)
Here is my ajax function
    public function ajax($data){
        if($data == "all"){
            $isi['data'] = $this->home_model->SelDokter();
            echo "<table class='table table-hover'>";
            $sp = "ajksdas";
            foreach($isi['data'] as $cetak){
                if($sp != $cetak['spe'] && $cetak['spe'] == "DU"){
                    echo "<thead><tr class='info'><td colspan='7' align='center'><strong>" . $cetak['spe'] . </tr>;
                    echo "<tr class='success'>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Nama Dokter</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Senin</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Selasa</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Rabu</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Kamis</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Jumat</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Sabtu</strong></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</thead>";
                    echo "<tbody>";
                }elseif($sp != $cetak['spe'] && $cetak['spe'] == "AG"){
                    echo "<thead><tr class='info'><td colspan='7' align='center'><strong>" . $cetak['spe'] </tr>;
                    echo "<tr class='success'>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Nama Dokter</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Senin</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Selasa</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Rabu</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Kamis</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Jumat</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Sabtu</strong></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</thead>";
                    echo "<tbody>";
                }elseif($sp != $cetak['spe']){
                    echo "<thead><tr class='info'><td colspan='7' align='center'><strong>" . $cetak['spe'] . "<strong></td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr class='success'>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Nama Dokter</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Senin</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Selasa</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Rabu</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Kamis</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Jumat</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Sabtu</strong></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</thead>";
                    echo "<tbody>";
                }
                echo "<tr class='warning'>";
                echo "<td><a style='color: #1B6B20;' href='" . base_url() . "home/dokter/" . $cetak['id_dktr'] . "'>" . $cetak['nama'] . "</a></td>";
                echo "<td align='center'>" . $cetak['senin'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td align='center'>" . $cetak['selasa'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td align='center'>" . $cetak['rabu'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td align='center'>" . $cetak['kamis'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td align='center'>" . $cetak['jumat'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td align='center'>" . $cetak['sabtu'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                $sp = $cetak['spe'];
            }
            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";
        }else{
            $spe = str_replace('%20', ' ', $data);
            $isi['data'] = $this->home_model->SelectDokter($spe);
            echo "<table class='table table-hover'>";
            $sp = "ajksdas";
            foreach($isi['data'] as $cetak){
                if($sp != $cetak['spe'] && $cetak['spe'] == "DU"){
                    echo "<thead><tr class='info'><td colspan='7' align='center'><strong>" . $cetak['spe'] . "<strong><br></tr>";
                    echo "<tr class='success'>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Nama Dokter</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Senin</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Selasa</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Rabu</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Kamis</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Jumat</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Sabtu</strong></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</thead>";
                    echo "<tbody>";
                }elseif($sp != $cetak['spe'] && $cetak['spe'] == "AG"){
                    echo "<thead><tr class='info'><td colspan='7' align='center'><strong>" . $cetak['spe'] . "<tr>";
                    echo "<tr class='success'>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Nama Dokter</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Senin</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Selasa</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Rabu</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Kamis</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Jumat</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Sabtu</strong></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</thead>";
                    echo "<tbody>";
                }elseif($sp != $cetak['spe']){
                    echo "<thead><tr class='info'><td colspan='7' align='center'><strong>" . $cetak['spe'] . "<strong></td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr class='success'>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Nama Dokter</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Senin</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Selasa</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Rabu</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Kamis</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Jumat</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td align='center'><strong>Sabtu</strong></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</thead>";
                    echo "<tbody>";
                }
                echo "<tr class='warning'>";
                echo "<td><a style='color: #1B6B20;' href='" . base_url() . "home/dokter/" . $cetak['id_dktr'] . "'>" . $cetak['nama'] . "</a></td>";
                echo "<td align='center'>" . $cetak['senin'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td align='center'>" . $cetak['selasa'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td align='center'>" . $cetak['rabu'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td align='center'>" . $cetak['kamis'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td align='center'>" . $cetak['jumat'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td align='center'>" . $cetak['sabtu'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                $sp = $cetak['spe'];
            }
            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }

and this is my select option to call the ajax function with the current selected option value
<select class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 form-control-static" type="text" name="spesialis" id="search" onChange="pilih(this.value)">
would love to get any help with this.
i have tried to change the ajax.js redirection but it still does not work. I don't know anything else that really work
